# I'm fetching some data from an api and when I'm logging the fetched data on the console it get's logged again and again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

Here's the function that's fetching the data from api:

```js
import axios from "axios";

const url = "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api";

export const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const {
      data: { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate },
    } = await axios.get(url);
    return { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate };
  } catch (error) {}
};
```

I'm using this function in App.js and passing the response to cards component via props, here's the code:

```js
import { fetchData } from "./api";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const response = await fetchData();
      setData({ data: response });
    }
    getData();
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Cards data={data} />
```

finally I'm logging the received props on console using this code but it gets logged again and again on console:

```js
const Cards = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
```

here's the screen shot of the console for your reference:[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8x0Z.png)

Answer (score 1):

useEffect gets executed everytime the component rerenders. Pass an empty array as an argument to useEffect to prevent that.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function getData() {
      const response = await fetchData();
      setData({ data: response });
    }
    getData();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass an empty list of dependencies in `useEffect` (run only once on mount):

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
        const response = await fetchData();
        setData({ data: response });
    }
    getData();
}, []);
```

otherwise it will run on every render